# Object null in my RMI server

Tags: java, object, null, rmi, remote-access

I send object on my RMI but , i find a null value.

Client.java :

```
service.InterfaceMathML stub = (service.InterfaceMathML) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/BK");

System.out.println("id : " +this.MTI_creerFichier.getId()); // Show 10


         int ValRetour = stub.Create(this.MTI_creerFichier, this.MTI_creerFichier.getId(),  "CreateFichier");
```

My Interface :

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface InterfaceMathML extends Remote{
    public int Create(Object unObject,String user, String unType)throws RemoteException;
}
```

My Server :

```
public int Create(Object unObject, String user, String unType) throws RemoteException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(unType)
        {
        case "CreateFichier" : 
                        System.out.println("Create Fichier");
            System.out.println((CreateFichier)unObject.getId());  // show Null
ystem.out.println(user);  // show userTest
                FichierImpl = new JDBCDAO_Fichier();
                this.validation = FichierImpl.Validation_ADD((CreateFichier)unObject, user);
                if ( this.validation == 1)   { this.entier = FichierImpl.add((CreateFichier)unObject, user); }
                else  { this.entier = this.validation; }
            break;
```

so Why I can't my Object is null on the server ?

Please for help.

**EDIT** 
In my MAINTestServer.java ( on my serverRMI)

```
 od = new MathMLServiceImpl() CreateFichier fi  = new  CreateFichier();
            fi.setLogin("test");            fi.setDossierParent("dossierparenttest");
            fi.setNomFichier("nomfichiertest");
            fi.setContenuFichier("essaie");

            int  val = od.Create(fi, "test", "CreateFichier"); System.out.println(val);
```

It's work

my RMI Server

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String url = "rmi://localhost:1099/BK";

        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            MathMLServiceImpl od = new MathMLServiceImpl();

            // je met a dispo un objet dans un url 
            Naming.rebind("rmi://localhost:1099/BK", od);
            System.out.println("Service pret");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

My CLientRMI :
I use Polymorphism to lanch class detect my class :

```
Class<?> actionClass = Class.forName("metierToInte." + nomDto + "Action");
            System.out.println(actionClass);


            Constructor<?> actionConstructe = actionClass.getConstructor(dto.getClass()); //dto.getClass()
            System.out.println("constructeur : " + actionConstructe.toString());
            ActionInteToMetier uneActione = (ActionInteToMetier) actionConstructe.newInstance(dto);


            System.out.println("action : " + uneActione.toString());
            //System.out.println("action : " + uneActione.toString());
            uneActione.executer();
```

It's work , for exemple my class "CreateFichierAction", I can send String it's work, but not my object

```
this.MTI_creerFichier =  creerFichier;
service.InterfaceMathML stub = (service.InterfaceMathML) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/BK");

System.out.println("id : " +this.MTI_creerFichier.getId()); // Show 10
         int ValRetour = stub.Create(this.MTI_creerFichier, this.MTI_creerFichier.getLogin(),  "CreateFichier");
         System.out.println("valeur retour rmi " + ValRetour);
```

soucr : CreerFichier

```
package dto.metierToInte;

import java.io.Serializable;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "")
@XmlRootElement(name = "CreateFichier")
public class CreateFichier
    extends Fichier
    implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    protected int id;

     public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
 }
```

It's work but , Not if my RMI CLIENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is not null only the id you are getting out of it is null

```
System.out.println((CreateFichier)unObject.getId());
```

if unObject was null then you must have got a NullPointerException. So check the getId() part.

Comment: I do this:    CreateFichier val = (dto.metierToInte.CreateFichier)unObject;
System.out.println(val.getId());  ///   show null

Comment: Again your object is not null the method getNomFichier() is returning null

Comment: If i Lanch my Object on my Server with a mainTest , it's work    But if I lanch my object on my RMI Client It's return null

Comment: Kindly post source for creerFichier

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52775/discussion-between-sanjeev-and-hann)

Comment: I test with many solution and I find it , the cause is the Class Fichier , I change this class and It's worked.   Thx for help #Sanjeev.  Thanks